# Preventing ob_end_clean() from sending headers?

Tags: php, http-headers

I am developing a PHP script that will be used in conjunction with other PHP scripts. My script pushes file to browser for download thus requiring buffer to be clean and headers not sent.

Now, let say that output buffer contains a character "a" and headers are not yet sent. What I am trying to do to get rid of buffer contents is using ob_end_clean() to empty the buffer completely. This works, however, this sends out the headers and I do not know how to prevent this:

```
var_dump(headers_sent());    // false
ob_end_clean();
var_dump(headers_sent());    // true
```

How to get rid of buffer contents without sending headers?

**UPDATE:**

There were concerns that my `var_dump()` is causing headers to be sent. Here's another test:

```
$sent_a = headers_sent();
ob_end_clean(); // or ob_clean(); etc..
$sent_b = headers_sent();
var_dump($sent_a);
var_dump($sent_b);
exit;
```

Result:

```
bool(false) bool(true)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce that problem if I call `ob_start()` before that code (the first `var_dump` gets discarded, the second one correctly states `false`). Do you _have_ an `ob_start()`?

Comment: As I stated before, there are some other scripts (I have no control over them) that leave some content in the output buffer. I'm checking this with ob_get_contents(). I am developing a WordPress plugin and would like to make it more failproof (or foolproof if you wish).

Comment: Any other code can end/flush your buffer as they like, if you don't trust them, there's little you can do about it. I _can_ tell you `ob_get_clean()` does _not_ send headers. Period. If headers _have_ been sent, it's been done at another place (and `headers_sent()` can tell you _where_).

Comment: Well that's really weird because one line above the `ob_end_clean()` headers are not sent yet and one line below the `ob_end_clean()` headers are already sent. There's no other code between those lines. No other script can interfere at that point. If I managed to clean buffer contents that were left by some other function without outputting anything to the browser, I would be fine then.

Comment: @sPaul: try assigning the return value of `headers_sent()` to a variable, and dump that... maybe it's `var_dump` that is sending the headers (which it tends to do, because its output is pushed straight to `stdout`), like I said in my answer

Comment: I have updated the question with another example which rules out `var_dump()`. Any ideas?

Comment: As Wrikken, I cannot reproduce [with `ob_start()`](http://3v4l.org/ISU1B). I *can* reproduce [without `ob_start()`](http://3v4l.org/ltI0q) but only because `ob_end_clean()` triggers a notice then (suppressing the notice with `@` fixes that). Are you really testing with that short snippet or only in the context of your Wordpress plug-in?

Comment: One option is the `OP` is _outside_ on `ob_start()`, but has used a `set_error_handler()` somewhere, which does not show any visible output but still sends some whitespace or something. `headers_sent($file,$line);var_dump($file.$line);` would really help here: it will tell that kind of thing, as I mentioned earlier....

Answer (score 0):

ob_end_clean() clears the buffer and turns of output buffering hence headers will be sent.
use ob_get_clean() instead to clear the buffer.

```
var_dump(headers_sent());    // false
ob_get_clean();
var_dump(headers_sent());    //Should be false still and buffer should be empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want with it, but the [first comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php#95773) on the ob_end_clean() page on php.net has a possible solution:

```
<?php
    // code

    $headers = array();
    if ( !headers_sent() ) {
      $headers = apache_response_headers();
    }

    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();

    if ( !empty( $headers ) ) {
      foreach ( $headers as $name => $value ) {
        header( "$name: $value" );
      }
    }

    // more code
?>
```